# Return all Rows that meet Criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

hy guys im learning google apps script to telegram bot,
i have write auto reply command and it success to reply, if i sent @02-02-2021 it will show all recorded data on that day, but on my code it just return only 1 row, i have trying anything but nothing work.
thanks for helping,

```
function searchDataByTanggalTransaksi(Tanggal){
  var rangeNameTransaksi = "Transaksi!A2:O";
  var rowsTransaksi = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(MYSSID, rangeNameTransaksi).values;
  var panjangTransaksi = rowsTransaksi.length;
  var Tanggal, Nama_Item, Divisi, Sat, Qty, Harga_Satuan, Debet, Kredit, Saldo, Peruntukan, Total  = "";
  var pesan ="";
    for (var row = 0; row < panjangTransaksi; row++ ){
    if ("@" + rowsTransaksi[row][1]==Tanggal){
      Tanggal = "   Tanggal Transaksi : " + rowsTransaksi[row][1];
      Nama_Item = rowsTransaksi[row][2];
      Divisi = rowsTransaksi[row][3];
      Sat = rowsTransaksi[row][4];
      Qty = rowsTransaksi[row][5];
      Harga_Satuan = rowsTransaksi[row][6];
      Debet = rowsTransaksi[row][7];
      Kredit = rowsTransaksi[row][8];
      Saldo = rowsTransaksi[row][9];
      Peruntukan = rowsTransaksi[row][12];
      Total = "   Total Transaksi : " + rowsTransaksi[row][14] + ",-";
      pesan += "<code>- " + Nama_Item + " |" + Qty + " " + Sat + " |" + Kredit + "</code>";
      
      return pesan ;
    }
   
  }
  return "Data tanggal tidak ditemukan";
}
function testgetRowsTransaksi(){
  var tanggal = searchDataByTanggalTransaksi("@2");
  var x = ""
  }
```

Comment: What is the variable that is supposed to contain two rows?

Comment: Pesan variable should return all the rows that meet criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the work around, on above method i was use `return`, but when i `sendText` it reply all the rows

```
case "/tgl" :
      var ssIdLogistik ="mySsId";
      var rangeNameTransaksi = "Transaksi!A2:O";
      var rowsTransaksi = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ssIdLogistik, rangeNameTransaksi).values;
      var panjangTransaksi = rowsTransaksi.length;
      var Tanggal, Nama_Item, Divisi, Sat, Qty, Harga_Satuan, Debet, Kredit, Saldo, Peruntukan, Total  = "";
      for ( var row = 0; row < panjangTransaksi; row++){
        if (rowsTransaksi[row][1] == perintah[1]){
          Tanggal = "   Tanggal Transaksi : " + rowsTransaksi[row][1];
          Nama_Item = rowsTransaksi[row][2];
          Divisi = rowsTransaksi[row][3];
          Sat = rowsTransaksi[row][4];
          Qty = rowsTransaksi[row][5];
          Harga_Satuan = rowsTransaksi[row][6];
          Debet = rowsTransaksi[row][7];
          Kredit = rowsTransaksi[row][8];
          Saldo = rowsTransaksi[row][9];
          Peruntukan = rowsTransaksi[row][12];
          Total = "   Total Transaksi : " + rowsTransaksi[row][14] + ",-";
          
          text += "<code>- " + Nama_Item + " |" + Qty + " " + Sat + " |" + Kredit+ ",-" + "</code>\n";
        }        
      }
      if(text == ""){
          text = "  Periksa format penulisan kode permintaan Tanggal.\n\n" +
                 "Melihat transaksi berdasarkan tanggal di awali dengan '/tgl_' dengan format /tgl_hh-bb-tttt:\n" +
                 "       /tgl_02-02-2021 \n";}      
      sendText(updates.message.chat.id, logoData + "<code>" + Tanggal + "\n----------\n" + text + "----------\n" + Total + "</code>");
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to store found values in array, I assume that you want to return `pesan` right?

So solution one of possible solutions is that every record that is found you store it into array, and then return whole array(if nothing found array length will be 0).

Here is there modified code:

```
function searchDataByTanggalTransaksi(Tanggal) {
  var rangeNameTransaksi = "Transaksi!A2:O";
  var rowsTransaksi = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(MYSSID, rangeNameTransaksi)
    .values;
  var panjangTransaksi = rowsTransaksi.length;
  var Tanggal,
    Nama_Item,
    Divisi,
    Sat,
    Qty,
    Harga_Satuan,
    Debet,
    Kredit,
    Saldo,
    Peruntukan,
    Total = "";
  var pesan = "";

  var resultArray = []; //Mentioned array to pass data in.

  for (var row = 0; row < panjangTransaksi; row++) {
    if ("@" + rowsTransaksi[row][1] == Tanggal) {
      Tanggal = "   Tanggal Transaksi : " + rowsTransaksi[row][1];
      Nama_Item = rowsTransaksi[row][2];
      Divisi = rowsTransaksi[row][3];
      Sat = rowsTransaksi[row][4];
      Qty = rowsTransaksi[row][5];
      Harga_Satuan = rowsTransaksi[row][6];
      Debet = rowsTransaksi[row][7];
      Kredit = rowsTransaksi[row][8];
      Saldo = rowsTransaksi[row][9];
      Peruntukan = rowsTransaksi[row][12];
      Total = "   Total Transaksi : " + rowsTransaksi[row][14] + ",-";
      pesan +=
        "<code>- " +
        Nama_Item +
        " |" +
        Qty +
        " " +
        Sat +
        " |" +
        Kredit +
        "</code>";

      return resultArray.push(pesan); //Data passed in per every iteration.
    }
  }
  return resultArray; //returning line
  return "Data tanggal tidak ditemukan"; // this line is obsolete
}
function testgetRowsTransaksi() {
  var tanggal = searchDataByTanggalTransaksi("@2");
  var x = "";
}
```

Comment: ive tried it sir but the bot reply "1.0".

Comment: Please send data of `rowsTransaksi`

Comment: data from google sheet sir ? can i know ur email ? i cant share it on public, coz it my company data ..

Comment: Just format of it, it can be two entries, and you can censure data.

Comment: this is the link of my Spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-dshe8x93yGlaYg_33GL-gnrt4EvSp_qxvn5_8MLnNU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not pretty sure, what kind of data **panjangTransaksi** variable holds, if you just want the all matching items in a concatenated string, you could try like below

```js
    function searchDataByTanggalTransaksi(Tanggal){
        var rangeNameTransaksi = "Transaksi!A2:O";
        var rowsTransaksi = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(MYSSID, rangeNameTransaksi).values;
        var panjangTransaksi = rowsTransaksi.length;
        return panjangTransaksi.reduce((acc, ele) => {
            let Nama_Item, Divisi, Sat, Qty, Harga_Satuan, Debet, Kredit, Saldo, Peruntukan, Total  = "";
            if ("@" + ele[1] == Tanggal){
                Tanggal = "   Tanggal Transaksi : " + ele[1];
                Nama_Item = ele[2];
                Divisi = ele[3];
                Sat = ele[4];
                Qty = ele[5];
                Harga_Satuan = ele[6];
                Debet = ele[7];
                Kredit = ele[8];
                Saldo = ele[9];
                Peruntukan = ele[12];
                Total = "   Total Transaksi : " + ele[14] + ",-";
                acc += "<code>- " + Nama_Item + " |" + Qty + " " + Sat + " |" + Kredit + "</code>";
              }
              return acc;
        }, '') ||  "Data tanggal tidak ditemukan";
      }
```

Comment: thanks for helping sir, i've tried it but no result/reply from bot from this method..

Answer (score 0):

The program will never enter this `if ("@" + rowsTransaksi[row][1]==Tanggal)` as `Tanggal` is undefined.